# How to calculate the Yes or No In status column when updating in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I have a GridView status with a DropDownList that is Yes or No.

After updating that status column. I have to count Total number Yes in that grid and popup the message that 90% records updated and saved successfully.

I've saved the records successfully, but how do I count the number of Yes choices in the status column?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Madhu
You will have to loop through all the rows and its all Cells to check if is null or not, and if you have template column and if it has control inside it like Label or TextBox than you will have to use FindControl method to get its value but if they are just bound column you can easily get it by following

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in grd.Rows)
{
       foreach (TableCell td in dr.Cells)
       {
           if (td.Text=="Yes")
           count++;
       }
}
```

now if you have template column just remove second loop of cells and just use dr.FindControl to find the control and check if its null or not

let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow GVRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {

      Dropdown d = (Dropdown)GVRow.FindControl("DropdownID");

      if(d.SelectedItem.Text=="Yes")
      {
         Count++;
      }

    }
```